# Windows Server 2003 - Terminal Server Login

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server

Is there a way to make it so that there is only one session available to a user and if for some reason they leave it open that when they reconnect it will always connect back into the old session and not make a new one?

Answer (score 3):

There is a Group Policy Setting under:

`Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Terminal Services`

called

`Restrict Terminal Server users to a single remote session`

There are many more usefull Settings.
[here are some...](http://www.msterminalservices.org/articles/Managing-Terminal-Services-Group-Policy.html)